# Arbitrary Union and Intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can we apply De Morgan law on arbitrary Unions and Intersections, or it is only restricted to finite ones?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, De Morgan laws hold for arbitrary unions and intersections, as can easily be verified directly. The proof in the finite case is essentially the same as for the infinite case.